# How do I make the contents shift less when vertically resizing a vim window?

Tags: vim-windows

If I open a long file in vim or neovim, and my cursor is not on the first line, and I make the window shorter by either resizing the terminal, or adding another split with `<C-W>s` or `:sp<cr>`, the top few lines get shifted out the top.

It seems like the content is shifted to keep the cursor at a proportionally-the-same position, e.g. "50% of the way down the window" - but I find this kind of jarring, and would like the lines to move less when adding splits.

For example,

```
nvim <(seq 100)
```

And move cursor to middle of window with `M`:

[image: single vim window with lines 1 through 19 visible and cursor on line 10]

Then split the window horizontally with `<C-W>s` or `:sp<cr>`:

[image: two vim windows, each with lines 6 through 14 visible, with cursor in bottom window on line 10]

And notice that lines 1 through 5 get pushed off screen, and the cursor is still roughly 50% down both windows on line 10.

I would prefer if vim attempted to keep the top 5 lines in view, that is:

- show lines 2 through 10 in each window, with the cursor having stayed on line 10

[image: two vim windows both showing lines 2 through 10 with cursor in bottom window on line 10]

I hope this is clear.

In other words, I would like if the line previously at the top of the window (`line("w0")`) gets stored *before* the resize and gets restored to as close to the top as possible e.g. with `zt`

I've looked at `:help resize`, but that seems to be for controlling the sizes of windows, not cursor or viewport positioning.

I've tried using:

```
autocmd VimResized * Hzt``
```

which is close to semantically what I want (previous top line as close as possible to the top of the window on window resize), but this seems to break resizing by the terminal window completely, and has no effect when splitting with `<C-W>s` or `:sp<cr>`.

As @dedowsdi points out, this is only triggered on vim application window resize, and there has no WinResized event. So this might not be the right approach.

Another idea I have is if I were able to have vim automatically type `H` *before* the resize and `` *after* the resize, the contents might stay put...

Comment: Can you provide a gif or screenshot? I'm having a hard time visualizing the behavior you're talking about, and it will be helpful to make sure others recreate the same problem in coming up with solutions.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I've added an example with (tall) screenshots!

Comment: made the screenshots shorter

Comment: @jameh I don't think it's completely possible to keep the exact behavior you're after... Maybe with a complex autocmd, we'll see. Meanwhile, check whether `'scrolloff'` is set, with `:set scrolloff?` and if it's set to a value larger than zero, then try `:set scrolloff=0` to see if that makes things slightly better (though not exactly what you want).

Comment: @filbranden I have `scrolloff=0` already

Comment: `VimResized` is only used for `vim` application window, there has no `WinResized` event.

Comment: @dedowsdi thanks, I updated the question with that info

Comment: `Autocmd` has hooks for before and after the change, doesn't it? Why not justmove cursor to line 2 (or the top line you want to stay in the viewport, can be decided dynamically..) inside the prechange hook, and move it back to where it was in the post-change command? Seems pretty straightforward to me. Or have I overlooked something somewhere? If this seems like a path you'd be willing to take, notify me, and I will write it as an answer in more detail, with the appropriate commands etc.